# Change DNS to Automatic DNS using script

Tags: windows-10, vpn, dns, script, batch-file

My computer has PureVPN which changes the DNS address every time I use this. This renders me unable to connect to the internet on my home and organizational networks, as they both use their own DNS servers. Is there a batch script that just automatically changes the IPv4 DNS settings to 'get automatically'? Because then I can just put it on my desktop and run it whenever it doesn't work. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

DNS configuration can be changed to dynamic with `netsh` command line tool. Run this command as administrator:

```
netsh interface ip set dnsservers name="Ethernet" source=dhcp
```

the `source=dhcp` option changes DNS source to be set dynamically. Here details from `netsh interface ip set dnsservers help` command:

```
source - One of the following values:
       dhcp: Sets DHCP as the source for configuring DNS servers for the specific interface.
       static: Sets the source for configuring DNS servers to local static configuration.
```

Also you can revert DNS server from dynamic to static i.e. change DNS to a specific IP address (e.g. 10.0.0.1) using this command:

```
netsh interface ip set dnsservers "Ethernet" static 10.0.0.1 primary
```

Change the `name=Ehternet` option with the name of your default network interface name.

#### Further reading:

- [Netsh Command Syntax, Contexts, and Formatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/netsh/netsh-contexts)
- [Microsoft DOS netsh command](https://www.computerhope.com/netsh.htm)
- [ss64 netsh](https://ss64.com/nt/netsh.html)